# Generic Repository Returns Different Objects in the Same List<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic, repository

I've come to an interesting problem today. There's a generic repository that I use in most of my projects like:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> CokGetir(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T Getir(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Ekle(T entity);
    void Duzenle(T entity);
    void Sil(T entity);
}
```

where CokGetir is:

```
public IEnumerable<T> CokGetir(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (predicate != null)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where(predicate);
    }
    return _objectSet.AsEnumerable();
}
```

As it's clear in the code, this method returns a list of objects asked in LINQ.

I use SignalR in this project and connect to an SQL database to store user messages and details. When I call CokGetir method to get latest users in a channel like:

```
var kullanicilar = _uow.Depo<ChatUserDetails>().CokGetir(p => p.YayinId.Equals(yayinId)).ToList();
```

> The kullanicilar variable contains 2 different objects (because there are 2 users connected). One is the data object 'Veri.ChatUserDetails' and the other is '{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ChatUserDetails_CF31378E4F985AB5B3AD99CDFCE21159AF26DDCA5BFBBB19F31B31537C3DEBA0}' as shown in the picture:

[image: Different Objects]

I need the dynamic object (both) because it holds the relationships with the other tables; on the other hand the `Veri.ChatUserDetails` does not have them. What may cause this confusion? I don't want to use plain `dbContext` while I'm using this dynamic repository so how can I overcome this situation?

**EDIT:**

`ChatUserDetails` as requested:

```
public partial class ChatUserDetails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string KullaniciId { get; set; }
    public int YayinId { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual YAY_Yayinlar YAY_Yayinlar { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the second edit with more information about the subject. This problem does not occur if the user connects to the hub for the first time. However, when the user refreshes the webpage, **SignalR** re-assigns the `ConnectionId` of the user and re-registers it to the chat channel. At this point, one of the `kullanicilar` objects loses all relationships with the tables.

Moreover, as I have observed, at the first run `kullanicilar` have 2 different objects (data and dynamic objects) when the new user connects and they both have the relationships with other tables. As aforementioned, when the user refreshes the page it loses the relationships.
I'm really confused.

Comment: On a hunch, could you try `var kullanicilar = _uow.Depo<ChatUserDetails>().CokGetir(p => p.YayinId.Equals(yayinId));` (without the `ToList`), also try once without the predicate to see if mostly dynamic objects are returned.

Comment: Please add to your post the definition of `ChatUserDetails`.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I've also tried it but the result is the same.

@FedericoDipuma added `ChatUserDetails` class.

Comment: Are you adding a new object to your `DbSet` and querying it before `SaveChanges` or closing the DbContext? If this is the case your `ChatUserDetails` may just be in the local cache, and thus is not fetched from the db.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I double checked the workflow to see if there's something as you've mentioned but I couldn't find any problems. After adding new objects to the `DbSet` I always call `SaveChanges`. 

However your thought of local cache seems reasonable to me, too. I'll investigate on that.